# Minor mode overriding another minor mode key binding

Tags: emacs

I installed Jedi mode in Emacs. I noticed that it overrides `C-c .` and `C-c ,` (`goto-definition` and `goto-definition-pop-marker respectively`).

Here is how I set it up in my init file:

```
(setq jedi:setup-keys t)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'jedi:setup)
```

I am using another mode called multiple-cursors that is set up as follows:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/multiple-cursors.el/")
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c .") 'mc/mark-next-like-this)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c ,") 'mc/mark-previous-like-this)
```

Once jedi-setup loads, it rebinds my `C-c .` and `C-c ,`. What I'd like to do is keep my multiple cursors bindings and remap Jedi's bindings. I tried adding this to the end of my Jedi setup but it ends up mapping the Jedi functions to both C-c./, and C-c j/k at the same time.

```
(setq jedi:key-goto-definition (kbd "C-c k"))
(setq jedi:key-goto-definition-pop-marker (kbd "C-c j"))
```

The reason this happens is because Jedi binds them on the regular C-c ./, mappings, then just adds another C-c j/k mapping.

How do I stop Jedi from completely not binding to the C-c ./, and only bind to C-c j/k?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unbind the keys you want in the Jedi mode keymap: just bind them to `nil` in that map.

Or change the order of the entries in `minor-mode-map-alist`.

See (elisp) [`Controlling Active Maps`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Controlling-Active-Maps.html).

Comment: How do I bind them to nil in that map? Doing: `(setq jedi:key-goto-definition nil)` throws an error in the init file. Will that preserve other minor modes key bindings for those bey bindings?

Comment: Learn to ask Emacs. `C-h r` opens the Emacs manual, then `i` finds stuff using completion. `i key binding` finds the part of the manual that talks about key bindings. [*The menu there*](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Key-Bindings.html) shows you a section `Init Rebinding`, for "Rebinding keys  with your initialization file". `(define-key THE-JEDI-MODE-MAP THE-KEY nil)` unbinds `THE-KEY` in that keymap.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Any idea idea why this doesn't work? `(eval-after-load 'jedi-mode '(prog (define-key jedi-mode-map (kbd "C-c d") nil)))`  C-c d still evaluates to whatever jodi-mode defined it as. When I remove `'(progn`, I get the symbol void error, which is because at init time it does not know jodi-mode. I am trying to avoid using `(require jedi-mode)`. Any ideas?

Comment: There are, I suspect, several typos in your comment (`prog`, `jodi`, etc.). But it looks like you might need to do `C-h f eval-after-load` - try using the name of the Jedi library (main) file as its first arg, instead of the mode-name symbol.

Comment: Yup, using jedi name as opposed to the mode-name symbol worked. That was it. Thanks!